# Get product attribute programatically

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute called 'Color', which is a select box,

I have a instance of the product, and I want to get the selected value of my field 'Color'. The problem is when I try to do it its always returning null.

This is my code:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute('prj_color')
```

This is always `null`. But if I try to get a different field, which is not a multivalued field, a textbox for example, I can get the value normally.

I'm using Magento 2.1.5. Someone know whats going on?

Comment: did you save any product with color attribute?

Comment: Yes I did. All products have the colors

Comment: prj_color is your attribute id?

Comment: Yes it is my attribute id

Comment: you can call like, $_product->getPrjColor()

Answer (score 1):

get VAlue

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFron‌​tend()->getValue($_p‌​roduct); ?>
```

LABEL

```
$address =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getStoreLabel();
```

Check this file ::Magento/Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Comment: I've try to use this loop before, and the result of `$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product)` is empty string

Comment: check my this post also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210071/how-to-get-selected-product-attribute-values-from-cart-magento-2/210078#210078

Comment: ttribute Value <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

Comment: Label ::$address =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getStoreLabel();

Comment: check my updated answare

Comment: the first solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getPrjColor(), 'prj_color') ?>
```

Try this

Comment: BHow can I get this `$_helper` variable?

Comment: is it working or not? because i have tried for getting my description for listing page so it may be work

Comment: you just want to put this code where you want to get your product attribute

Comment: Nope, it didn't work